Can excessive checking of an Esrog be considered nezek?
Here's the situation: Someone in a Shul is selling arba minim sets for the whole Shul. The Rav agreed to check them all. So I would assume there's a chezkas kashrus when I buy the set and I have no need to check it. Let's say I did check it, for some reason. And at first glance it looks fine, and it's only after extensive checking that I find a very subtle spot that turns out being a p'sul. Now, I would assume that if I had opened the box and found an obviously-passul esrog in there I would be able to get my money back from the distributor, no questions asked, because the chazaka vanishes right away. However, given that this p'sul wasn't so obvious and I found it only after checking very very carefully (surely not something I needed to do given the kashrus stamp the Rav gave), does the distributor have the right to demand money for damage I caused him? Surely I can't use this esrog and therefore should have the right to demand my money back from the distributor, and would give the passul esrog back to the distributor. But had I done the "right" thing by just accepting the esrog and not checking it excessively, I would have been able to use that esrog relying on the chezkas kashrus, and the only reason this esrog is passul is because of my excessive checking. Essentially, I caused the distributor's esrog to become passul. So does the disributor have the right to demand payment from me for damaging his esrog?

Seems like the rabbi made the mistake not you

@DoubleAA True, and there are probably repercussions for that, but does the distributor have any claim against me since I received it bichezkas kosher?

"given that this p'sul wasn't so obvious and I found it only after checking very very carefully" why does that matter?

@DoubleAA I don't know for sure that it does, but to go to the other extreme for a second, if I opened the box and found an apple instead of an esrog, there was never a point where I would have a chazaka to rely on and I assume there wouldn't even be a question - you can't fault me for making the "esrog" passul. But in this case, to the naked eye there was no reason to believe the chazaka was faulty

I can fault you. If you'd been blind you wouldn't have noticed

@DoubleAA Right but the average person isn't blind. You can't blame someone for not being blind, that's absurd. The assumption when you open your esrog box is that you'll see it, admire it a little, and that's it. Not that you'll examine it in a way that is searching meticulously for issues after you already have a kashrus stamp on it. The average person is not doing that

Why does it matter what the average person does? Either you can rely on the chazaka blindly or you can double check. What good is a chazaka that can't be relied on blindly?

@DoubleAA There's such a thing as איתרע ליה חזקתיה. For example, if you check an Eruv on Friday afternoon you can usually rely on it for Shabbos, but if, while you're checking, you see landscapers chopping down tree branches right near an eruv line, there's a good chance you lose the chazaka. So if there's a reason that slaps you across the face indicating a chazaka might not be good, you cannot blindly rely on it. In the situation of my question, however, reliance on the chazaka is very reasonable-there's no איתרע ליה חזקתיה slapping you in the face. I decided to do an excessive check on it

Sure there's such a thing but the rule of איתרע חזקתיה doesn't discuss how you came to find the ריעותא. However you found it you found it.

Let's just take a different tact since you insist on a very strong conception of חזקה even against metzius. Would you buy from a seller who refused to let you check? I assume not. Thus the seller allows you to check and return if there's a problem.

@RabbiK if you're going to edit, go for "invalid"

@DoubleAA Point taken. So let's change the case to be a little to be more practical: I'm looking through the esrogim this distributor has in stock. Again, they were all approved by the Rav. Before I buy anything I examine some closely and find one with a subtle but unquestionable p'sul. Whether likely or not, it's within the distributor's right to tell me not to examine his inventory closely. Can he now demand payment from me for "damaging" his previously-kosher esrog?

Any spot that requires extensive checking is not Halachically significant and has no effect on the Esrog's kashrus.

@N.T. And just to clarify both for myself and others who might be confused by this...the reason you see so many pictures of gedolim using magnifying glasses and similar instruments is because they're checking many esroging at once and since their eyes get tired, they need that just to be able to see easily viewable spots?

They might be checking if it is chaser (missing a piece) or if the spot is visible but they are not sure of the color.
